# Why is the builtin confirm() dialog so rarely used?

Tags: javascript, web, accessibility, user-experience

I assume the builtin `confirm()` dialog is well maintained and has good usability and accessibility compared to custom solutions. It is also easier to implement. So I tend to advice people to use it.

However, I noticed that most "professional" websites use some custom mechanism. Are there any strong arguments against `confirm()`?

Comment: If only it was just about the default confirm modal...most people/sites hate the look of every default component (scroll bars, buttons, dropdowns, ...). Most of the time, you have to re-implement or install packages for those components to enable custom styling.

Answer (score 2):

It mostly comes down to styling. You cannot customize the default `confirm()` dialogue.

But if you want to make something simple, it is a good way for fast results and it is [supported on all newer platforms.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)